# Backbone.babysitter error running Famo.us Asteroids game example

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, famo.us

Anyone know why I'm getting these errors in Chrome console, when running this sample Astroids game (written with www.Famo.us):
https://github.com/zgardner/famoids

I did the usual `npm install && bower install` and `grunt serve`. I have npm and bower already installed. Checked the `app/lib` folder, it shows the files Chrome says it can't find.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)       http://localhost:1337/lib/backbone.babysitter/lib/amd/backbone.babysitter.js
Uncaught Error: Script error for: backbone.babysitter
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:141
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)     http://localhost:1337/lib/backbone.wreqr/lib/amd/backbone.wreqr.js
Uncaught Error: Script error for: backbone.wreqr
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
```

Answer (score 0):

Bower is using the latest babysitter and wreqr and the paths have been updated since the code for famoids was last updated.

Go to `app/src/requireConfig.js` and change these two paths from:

```
'backbone.wreqr': '../lib/backbone.wreqr/lib/amd/backbone.wreqr',
'backbone.babysitter': '../lib/backbone.babysitter/lib/amd/backbone.babysitter',
```

to:

```
'backbone.wreqr': '../lib/backbone.wreqr/lib/backbone.wreqr',
'backbone.babysitter': '../lib/backbone.babysitter/lib/backbone.babysitter',
```

Comment: OK, got it, will try this out. Good reason to force versions on dependencies -)

Comment: Yeah better to limit the version. How did it go?